# Is there a way to print the code of an object instead of its value using R?

Tags: r, console, expression

For example, if I have the following object:

```
fz <- (1 / sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-(Z^2) / 2)
```

If I have already assigned Z, I get a value returned when I enter "fz"

```
> Z <- 0.03057164
> fz
[1] 0.3987559
```

However, I would like a quick way to print the underlying code for fz so that the code I type results in:

```
(1 / sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-(Z^2) / 2)
```

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: perhaps if you made a function out of it?

Comment: You need to use a function() wrapper so the object is saved as a closure.

Comment: Generally if you simply run a function's  name the function code will print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mtoto suggests,

```
fz <- function(Z) (1 / sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-(Z^2) / 2)
```

Then by typing `fz`, you will get

```
function(Z) (1 / sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-(Z^2) / 2)
```